# Java- Servlet - redirecting request with a new body

Tags: java, xml, servlets, request, forwarding

I'm writing a Servlet in Java, that basically, gets a request with a XML in the Requests body, and then changes a few things in the XML and redirect/foreword the request with The new XML to a different Servlet that's on the same server, but its  on a different web app.

I'm using doPost.

How do i do that? can i find code example any where?

Plus, whats the correct method to use:?

`request.getRequestDispatcher().include /request.getRequestDispatcher().foreword / response.sendRedirect()`  or  do i need to use the: `HttpServletRequestWrapper`?

this is what i have so far:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

     String body = getBody(request);
     MapXml mapXml = new MapXml(body, "C:\\Projects\\XmlMapper\\output.xml","C:\\Projects\\XmlMapper\\output\\");
     String outputXml = mapXml.getOutputXml();



}
public static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    String body = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    body = stringBuilder.toString();
    return body;
}
```

And i have no idea how to continue on from here. I'm new to the servlet world..
Thanks!!!
**Cheers:)**

Comment: Where's your code? What does the javadoc of those methods say? What happens when you google for "difference between forward and redirect"?

Comment: if I'm asking here, i probably didn't get the answer i was looking for..